# How to show/hide textfield according to the change in drop down using jquery?

Tags: 7, javascript

```
$(".form-select").change(function () { 
  if (this.value == "1") {
    $('.form-item-example').stop(true,true).show(700);
  }
  else{
    $('.form-item-example').stop(true,true).hide(700);
  }
});
```

This is what i have used in my js file but it is hiding the text fields when any of the drop down in the form is changed, I'm having 3 drop downs in the form.

Comment: You don't have to use custom jQuery at all - you can use the Form API's #states functionality: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states

Comment: I have seen the article, but please please tell me is it possible for drop down

Comment: Yes, you can do it with drop downs.

Comment: is there any example

Comment: Look at the $form['brands'] example here: https://wunder.io/blog/using-the-drupal-7-form-api-states-system-to-create-conditions-between-form-elements/2014-01-20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar using [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module which is an interface for the [States API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7.x) or you can use States API if you are comfortable writing custom code.